# Data Type Mismatch In Criteria Expression (Access 2013)

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an access database with linked excel tables( each table is an excel sheet)
In one of my tables, there is a currency field called 'Salary'. The format is **$#,##0.00**. As such, for cases where salary is 0, the field value is **$0.00**.

I wrote a query to exclude records where the salary value is 0. In the criatera box, i plase <> "$0.00", however when I run the query, i receive the error **Data Type Mismatch In Criteria Expression**. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a Decimal field with a string, try using <>0 in your criteria box.

Comment: Thanks! This works. I realise I do not need to use $0.00 since Access resolves $0.00 to 0